# DialogService which can return a result and closes Window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I wanted to have a DialogService that can return an arbitrary result. The views to be displayed are implemented as UserControls, and UserControls cannot close themselves (nor directly the parent window), so I decided to do the closing of the window via the DialogService. The UserControls do not have a ViewModel.
So I came up with following interface

```
/// <summary>
/// Interface for views/view models, the user has to acknowledge something.
/// </summary>
/// This interface provides an event which signalizes when the user finished making their choice.
/// This can be used for continuing operation or closing a dialog/window.
public interface ISelectionDone
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when user has made their selection.
    /// </summary>
    event EventHandler SelectionDone;
}

/// <summary>
/// Generic variant of ISelectionDone
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Result type</typeparam>
public interface ISelectionDone<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when user has made their selection.
    /// </summary>
    event EventHandler SelectionDone;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the result.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The result.
    /// </value>
    T Result { get; set; }
}
```

This interface is implemented by a UserControl.

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Example.UserView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d" MaxWidth="1000" MaxHeight="700">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- Information for the user -->
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt" />
        <UniformGrid Columns="2" Grid.Row="1">
            <Button x:Name="ok" Content="OK" Click="ok_Click" />
            <Button x:Name="nok" Content="Not OK" Click="nok_Click" />
        </UniformGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```
public partial class UserView : UserControl, ISelectionDone, ISelectionDone<bool>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when choice is acknowledged / selection is done.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler SelectionDone;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the user choice
    /// </summary>
    public bool? UserChoice { get; set; }

    public CalibrationAcknowledgementView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void nok_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsCalibrationAcknowledged = false;
        OnSelectionDone();
    }

    private void ok_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsCalibrationAcknowledged = true;
        OnSelectionDone();
    }

    void OnSelectionDone()
    {
        if (SelectionDone != null)
        {
            SelectionDone(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the result
    /// </summary>
    public bool Result
    {
        get
        {
            return UserChoice == true;
        }
        set
        {
            UserChoice = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the DialogService

```
/// <summary>
/// Service for showing dialogs^/ other content synchronously.
/// </summary>
public interface IDialogService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Shows "any" content inside a window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="content">The content.</param>
    /// content must implement interface ISelectionDone to report finished user interaction
    void ShowContent(ISelectionDone content);

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows "any" content inside a window. Returns a Result
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Result type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="content">The content.</param>
    /// <returns>the result</returns>
    /// content must implement interface ISelectionDone to report finished user interaction and result
    T ShowContentWithResult<T>(ISelectionDone<T> content);

    // ... left out irrelevant parts here

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the owner window for all dialogs.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="window">The window.</param>
    void SetOwner(Window window);
}
```

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides a IDialogService which shows modal dialogs.
/// </summary>
internal class ModalDialogService : IDialogService
{
    /// Dispatcher to ensure execution on current thread
    private readonly Dispatcher dispatcher = App.Current.Dispatcher;

    /// main window, used as owner for dialogs
    private Window main;

    public void ShowContent(ISelectionDone content)
    {
        dispatcher.Invoke(
            new Action(() =>
            {
                Window w = new Window();
                w.Content = content;
                w.Owner = main;
                w.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
                content.SelectionDone += (s, e) => w.Close();
                w.ShowDialog();
            }));
    }

    public T ShowContentWithResult<T>(ISelectionDone<T> content)
    {
        return dispatcher.Invoke<T>(
            () =>
            {
                Window w = new Window();
                w.Content = content;
                w.Owner = main;
                w.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
                content.SelectionDone += (s, e) => w.Close();
                w.ShowDialog();
                return content.Result;
            });
    }

    // ... irrelevant parts left out

    public void SetOwner(Window window)
    {
        // this must be done on UI thread
        dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            // can be
            Debug.Assert(window != null, "window should not be null");

            main = window;
        });
    }
}
```

Back I when wrote this I annotated this is "a maybe somewhat ugly solution", if I remember correctly I didn't really like closing the window via the DialogService and this event.

So now I'm asking here, is the interface and the implementation okay? Is that "MVVM-ish"?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> public void SetOwner(Window window)
> {
>     // this must be done on UI thread
>     dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
>     {
>         // can be
>         Debug.Assert(window != null, "window should not be null");
>
>         main = window;
>     });
> }
> ```

IMO that looks like a textbook case for an `ArgumentNullException`.

---

> ```
> /// <summary>
> /// Interface for views/view models, the user has to acknowledge something.
> /// </summary>
> /// This interface provides an event which signalizes when the user finished making their choice.
> /// This can be used for continuing operation or closing a dialog/window.
> public interface ISelectionDone
> {
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Occurs when user has made their selection.
>     /// </summary>
>     event EventHandler SelectionDone;
> }
> ```

Nitpick, but the verb is *to signal*, not *to signalize* - should be "*[...] which **signals** when [...]*". I'm not too fond of the naming here, `ISelectionDone` doesn't seem to be following the [interface naming guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bc1fexb(v=vs.71).aspx), more specifically:

> - Name interfaces with nouns or noun phrases, or adjectives that describe behavior. For example, the interface name **IComponent** uses a descriptive noun. The interface name **ICustomAttributeProvider** uses a noun phrase. The name **IPersistable** uses an adjective.

`ISelectionDone` isn't a noun or a phrase, it's just the name of your event with an "`I`" stuck in front. I can't think of a good name for it at the moment though, but *naming is hard*, so I'll give you that.

---

> *Is that "MVVM-ish"?*

Not quite. Not only "*the UserControls do not have a ViewModel*", but the window itself doesn't have a `DataContext` either, so it's hardly a WPF-ish solution, too.

The `x:Name` attributes don't need to be there. WPF doesn't need to name its controls. If you *think* you need an `x:Name`, you probably don't *need* one. And if you *need* one, then there's a high probability you're doing something wrong, or at least more complicated than it needs to be (and *that's* something that's easily done in WPF!).

The interface, the event, the click handlers... all that is really a poor substitute for what should be a `CommandBinding` and an `ICommand` - if you were using a ViewModel, the command's `Execute` logic could be implemented there, and invoked automatically by the framework rather than through some manual event-raising and registering.

Speaking of which...

> ```
> return dispatcher.Invoke<T>(
>     () =>
>     {
>         Window w = new Window();
>         w.Content = content;
>         w.Owner = main;
>         w.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
>         content.SelectionDone += (s, e) => w.Close();
>         w.ShowDialog();
>         return content.Result;
>     });
> ```

This is quite a lot of instructions to put in an anonymous delegate, it could have been written in an actual method. `w` is a bad identifier for something that could have been simply `view`.

Structurally, I don't like how the service needs to know about the visual content of the window/control it's displaying, let alone about the way it's being sized to content - it's completely mixing responsibilities and abstraction levels IMO.

Comment: Would calling [Window.GetWindow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.window.getwindow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the click handler (maybe in addition to setting the Command) be a better solution in this case? Since closing a window is a view concern, the UserControl should be able to do it, shouldn't it?